# BlackBerry Maps and Location App

Tags: google-maps, blackberry, maps

I have looked extensively for a solution all over the Internet

What I need is a map in a field within my application in Blackberry 8310
(I don't mind if the solution comes from using OS 5.0+).

I can get a static map in there using a browser field or invoke Google Maps Application

But thats not what I want. For 1, I cannot use static maps to hover over a pin marked on the map and get its details, I cannot use static maps to pan and zoom around. And for the 2nd option, I cannot take it for granted that the user has Google Maps app on his blackberry phone, neither can I click on a landmark in Google maps and expect control to come back to my application for details.

Any ideas?

Tanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`net.rim.device.api.lbs.MapField`

to display a map on a screen.

to pan use `void net.rim.device.api.lbs.MapField.move(int dx, int dy)`
to zoom use `void net.rim.device.api.lbs.MapField.setZoom(int zoom)`

I am not 100% sure, but I think MapField even does have some kind of fallback, useing the mapping service available on the device (BlackBerry maps or Google Maps).